# How to localize or internationalize the map control i.e zoom and pan control

Tags: mapquest

I am adding multilingual support to my map (Mapquest javascript sdk v7.0.s).
I want to show the title shown in mouse over the control(say pan or zoom) in french.

With reference to below page, i understand i have to override the control. http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/custom

Since i want to modify only small portion of the original code.

1. Where i will find the original source code to download.
2. What is best practice to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way I did it.

```
MQA.withModule('largezoom',function(){
    map.addControl(new MQA.LargeZoom());
    var rosette=(document.getElementById('panControlImageMapmap'))?document.getElementById('panControlImageMapmap').childNodes:document.getElementById('panControlImageMap').childNodes;
    rosette[0].title="meilleur ajustement";
...
});
```